# SQL keep selecting records based on result of last selection

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title of this post is probably not correct.  I have a table like the one below and I need SQL that will select all the records that are related to a certain value.  This is a "history" table that keeps track of ID values where I keep track of what an ID used to be. Record 1 splits into two and becomes 2 and 3, then maybe 2 and 3 merge together and become 4.  For example:

```
OldID    NewID
1        2
1        3
3        4
5        4
2        6
2        7
```

In the above example, record 1 has become 2 and 3.  Record 4 is 3 and 5 merged together.  Record 2 was part of 1 and has now split into 6 and 7.

So if we look at record NewID = 7, it is related to record 2, 6, and 1

NewID 4 is related to 3, 5, 1, and 2.

So in the end I need syntax that will select all records that were related in this way to NewID = X.  Is this possible?  Is this like a recursion?

Comment: Do a google search for recursive cte. There are literally thousands and thousands of examples of this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```
declare @x int = 4
;with cte as (
select oldid, newid from table4 where newid = @x

union all

select t.oldid, t.newid from cte c inner join table4 t on c.OldId = t.newid
) select * from cte
```

Comment: Yes, that does what I need to do, thank you Kannan.  I was hoping to avoid cte but I can work with it.